# excel formula for previous quarters

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to pull up the previous quarter and year like in the Column J, for the Oct 20, it should return Q3 20 instead of Q4 20.
Currently my formula only returns the correct quarter but I would need the previous to last quarter and year?

[image: picture]

Comment: Change both `H17` references to `EDATE(H17, -3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the quarter | year corresponding to 3 months ago, i.e. :

> *"previous quarter & year"*

simply replace col H date references with `edate(date,-3)`.  Cell J17 formula to enter is then:

```
="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(EDATE(H17,-3))/3,0)&" "&YEAR(EDATE(H17,-3))
```

[image: Screenshot - application]

If you have Office 365 compatible version of Excel, you could shorten (albeit ever so slightly in this case) with the `let` function as so:

```
=LET(x,EDATE(H17,-3),"Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(x)/3,0)&" "&YEAR(x))
```